# Passing a gesture to a UIContextMenuConfiguration preview controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uikit

I'm new to iOS. I have had this problem for some time now and have not found a solution yet. I have a UICollectionView in a UIViewController, as UIContextMenuConfiguration for the cells I show a preview of a second UIViewController. I would like to pass a LongPress gesture to this second controller. So far I have tried some approaches, but the UILongPressGestureRecognizer in the first controller always gets canceled as soon as the preview is displayed. If I create my own GestureRecognizer in the second controller, it will always be ignored. I would be very grateful for help. Cheers!

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, contextMenuConfigurationForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath, point: CGPoint) -> UIContextMenuConfiguration? {
        let configuration = UIContextMenuConfiguration(identifier: indexPath as NSCopying) { () -> UIViewController? in
            let secondViewController = SecondViewController()
                return secondViewController
            } actionProvider: { (_) -> UIMenu? in
            return nil
            }
        return configuration
    }
```

Comment: It's very likely the framework cancels any dev-instantiated gesturerecognizer from the source controller of the UIContextMenuConfiguration. As in, if you're using the UIContextMenuConfiguration class, Apple assumes you're adhering to their UI and UX principles and designs, and don't prioritize UIContextMenuConfiguration's recognizers over yours. I think your best bet would be to try and develop your own UIContextMenu class with UIView and UIViewController subclasses, that would support what you're trying to do.

Comment: I did that and got the interface I wanted. I guess sometimes it's easier to implement something new than customizing already present. Thank you very much for your support!